# maximum entropy probability distribution on $SO(3)$ given Frechet mean and variance

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Consider the metric space $(SO(3, \mathbb{R}), d)$ for some metric $d$. Given $x \in SO(3, \mathbb{R})$ and $v > 0$, is there any popular maximum entropy probability distribution on $SO(3, \mathbb{R})$ such that $\arg \min_{y \in SO(3, \mathbb{R})} \mathbb{E}[d^2(y,X)] = x$ and $\mathbb{E}[d^2(x,X)] = v$?

I am new to this field so any point to articles/books/lecture notes will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is $X$ in your notations?

Comment: $X \in SO(3,\mathbb{R})$ is a random rotation matrix.